# Why won't my divs align horizontally?

Tags: css, html, alignment

Problem i cannot figure. I have a very simple page layout. Two div inside a container. The Div at the top, div "navigation-block", contains a ul and li's for a menu. From the CSS you will see it has a width of 30%. The div "bio" which is currently below the "navigation-block" div has a width of 30%.

All i want is for the "bio" div to float to the right of the "navigation-block" div. I've ensured there is no clear:both or clear:right on the "navigation-block". Ive tried float:left and float:right on the "bio" div and display:inline, but no joy what am i missing.

Html is straightforward, and no mistakes ive checked.

CSS below

```
.gridContainer {
position:relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;   
}

#bio {
width: 30%;
height:auto;
background-color: rgba(256,256,256,0.2);
color: rgba(256,256,256, 0.8);
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid white;
}

#navigation-block {
position:relative;
width:30%;  
}
```

the below is the rest of the menu CSS

```
ul#sliding-navigation
{
list-style: none;
font-size: .75em;
padding: 0;
}

ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element h3,
ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element a
{
display: block;
width: 60%;
padding: 2% 2%;
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 1%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

```
ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element h3
{
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.6);
font-weight: normal;
border: 1px solid white;

}

ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element a
{
color: #000;
background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.4);
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element a:hover { color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.8); }


<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">

 <div id="navigation-block">
        <ul id="sliding-navigation">
            <li class="sliding-element"><h3>Zion City Limits</h3></li>
            <li class="sliding-element"><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="sliding-element"><a href="#">Danny</a></li>
            <li class="sliding-element"><a href="#">Dylan</a></li>
            <li class="sliding-element"><a href="#">Bill</a></li>
            <li class="sliding-element"><a href="#">Rich</a></li>
            <li class="sliding-element"><a href="#">John</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>

<div id="bio">This is the content for Layout Div Tag </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any Help appreciated

thanks

Comment: Show us the html code also

Comment: You'll get a lot more help if you can post your HTML or create a jsfiddle with all of your code.

Comment: did you try setting float left on both "bio" and "navigation-block" ?

Comment: Hard to say without any HTML examples.  Also, would be very helpful if you had a fiddle or sample link. Ultimately though, you need to learn to tools of how to figure these things out, so I will suggest you use Firebug or similar web developer tools where you can easily highlight DOM elements, change CSS on them, etc. to figure out why something is displaying the way it is.

Comment: you're missing the `bio div`

Comment: Brain Glaz -  that was it, i didn't put a float:left on the "navigation-block", didn't realise i needed to do that. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but to help the next person that comes across this post.

```
display: inline-block;
```

This must be used for aligning divs inside of other divs when the parent div's height is not static.

Comment: Try adding a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) example with more robust code. That will help this answer!

Comment: Here's a simple one real quick. :) [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eLBht/)

Answer (score 0):

Two options here...

```
 #bio, #navigation-block {
   ...
   display:inline-block
}
```

or:

```
#bio, #navigation-block {
   ...
   float: left
}
```

`div`s are block level elements and won't position next to each other by default